# How to map MySQL Geometry type property with EF Core to .NET Core Geometry type property?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, spatial

I have an application (.NET Core 3.1) what pulls data from the database and works with that.

Previously the database was an Ms Sql Server, i was able to use NetTopologySuite to handle the Spatial Data from the database.

Now the database has been changed to MySQL, and NetTopologySuite [doesn't support that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial).

The aplication uses the [MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore) connector.

Definition:

```
public class ExampleObjectDefinition{

        public Geometry GeoLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```
public class ExampleObjectDefinitionConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<ExampleObjectDefinition>
{
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ExampleObjectDefinition> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Example_Table");


            builder.Property(_ => _.SpatialTypedLocation)
                   .HasColumnName("SPATIAL_LOCATION");
        }
}
```

Is there a way to map the type?

Thanks!

Comment: Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (EF Core provider for MySQL) may eventually have support, but it's not implemented yet: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/488. You could open a PR 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handled with additional conversion in the configuration.

The source is a view in my case, so the setter is not used anyway.

```
public class ExampleObjectDefinitionConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<ExampleObjectDefinition>
{
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ExampleObjectDefinition> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Example_Table");

            builder.Property(_ => _.SpatialTypedLocation)
                   .HasColumnName("SPATIAL_LOCATION")
                   .HasConversion<MySqlGeometry?>
                    (
                       v => new MySqlGeometry(v.PointOnSurface.X, v.PointOnSurface.Y), 

                       value => value == null ? null : new Point(value.Value.XCoordinate.Value, value.Value.YCoordinate.Value)
                    );

        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I used for EF 6, .Net Core 6:

```
            services.AddDbContext<AWSMariaSQLDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("AWSMariaSQLDataConnection"), Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.Parse("10.6.10-mariadb"), 
                options => options.UseNetTopologySuite())
            );
```

Then in my model builder:

```
        entity.Property(e => e.Location)
               .HasColumnName("Location")
               .HasColumnType("point");
```

My Model:

```
public Point Location { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please, is there a difference between `public Point Location ` and 'public Geometry Location '

Comment: I would guess no, as the point is just a type of geometry. Test it out or read the documentation.

Comment: You're right, after some googling, I found an answer like yours, I think I can insert any data in a Geometry column that is a subtype of it (Point, Polygon, Multi-Polygon, ...), am I right? Thanks